# How to get count returned by countQuery in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using both `nativeQuery` and `countQuery` in my `Repository` layer as:

```
@Query(value = "select * FROM Person p where p.forename = :forename and p.surname = :surname",
countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM Person p where p.forename = :forename",
  nativeQuery = true)
User findByForenameAndSurname(@Param("surname") String lastname,
                             @Param("forename") String firstname);
}
```

I want integer count returned by this `countQuery` and I want to use that count to construct `PageRequest` object which I want to use for `nativeQuery` to get the `Page` object. Can I access this count before constructing `PageRequest` object?
Is there any way to get the value returned by `countQuery`?

Comment: No there is no way expect you create an other query just for the cound. But I don't understand why you need the count.

Comment: @simon-martinelli my count query represent the num of records as i want to return to the user, which is actual count of objects but my native query is returning multiple rows(  kinda have 4 different rows for one obj in the table). I need this count to form my native query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the page then simply return it:

```
@Query(value = "select * FROM Person p where p.forename = :forename and p.surname = :surname",
      countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM Person p where p.forename = :forename",
      nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findByForenameAndSurname(@Param("surname") String lastname,
                             @Param("forename") String firstname);
}
```

The Page object will contain all you need.

Comment: Thanks. But suppose `countQuery` is returning count as 1 and my `nativeQuery` is returning 4 records then whether my page object will have 4 records or 1 record?

Comment: If this is the case you are breaking the rules. Count MUST return the number that the query will return!!!!

Comment: @TheRealChx1014 where do you see a non native count query?